# ES not using all the memory assigned to it

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running ES (1.6) for development on my MacBook PRO and I am trying to give ES more memory to use for improving query speed

I've tried

```
export ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g
```

When I try `ps` the process is named:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -Djava.awt.headless=true -
```

since -Xms and -Xmx are set correctly I see it's  getting the message

but it still only uses 1gb of memory even if there is free memory

Does any one know what is the reason?
Thanks

Comment: What do you get when running this: `curl 'localhost:9210/_cat/nodes?v&h=hm'`?

Comment: I get this:   hm 
1.9gb

Comment: There you go, that's the current max heap, which is 2GB as you configured.

Comment: I see, but in my Activity Monitor I see a java process and it never exceeds 1gb. and the queries didn't get any faster

Comment: It simply means your ES doesn't need more memory (yet) and your queries won't be faster just by throwing more memory into it. There might be  other ways to improve the speed of your queries, though.

Comment: have you tried bootstrap.mlockall: true option too?